# What is the best approach to getting started with IoC in .NET

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, refactoring, inversion-of-control

I've been reading up on IoC which seems to be a very broad and vague guideline. I have also been tasked with refactoring an enterprise system to make it more maintainable and testable. IoC promises to help me with these two aspects of the system.

What is the best approach to start using an IoC pattern? Should I focus on something more specific like dependency injection or should I try to rather wrap my head around the broader aspects of IoC?

I am very new to this and feel that I'm in in way over my head. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use it. Really. You'll get the hang of it :D I didn't really "get" DI/IoC until I started using [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net) - but ServiceStack comes with Funq and so it was just "so darn easy to use" in a way that actually *made my life easier*. Also, the [Castle Windsor documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is really good in explaining DI/IoC in layman terms: some things are Services, some Components, and everything else is an implementation detail .. oh, and *avoid the Service Locator anti-Pattern*!

Comment: The Service Locator Pattern (and XML configurations!) is probably why it took me so many years to start using DI - I could never quite figure out why doing "new" without `new` was supposed to be a good thing ..

Comment: @pst: Go ahead and explain why it's an anti pattern. One bad use case (line of business apps) do not make it an anti pattern. Or do you want to remove the IoC integration from ASP.NET MVC etc? http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/09/service-locator-is-not-an-anti-pattern/

Comment: @jgauffin Notice how I didn't supply the "anti-" in the subsequent comment. There are plenty of articles online arguing every which way - I would consider it more of a "last resort" option as sometimes other injection mechanisms are not possible or less ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have said start with dependency injection. But without a container you'll end up doing a lot of work which have to be refactored again.

So I would start by learning how to use a container in a small test project and make sure that I understand the different lifetime scopes before continuing.

You could also read my IoC article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386164/Get-injected-into-the-world-of-inverted-dependenci

Answer (score 3):

There's only one possible answer to this question :-). Read [this book](http://www.manning.com/seemann/):

[image: Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann]

Comment: So you say that delving straight into DI is the best approach to practicing good IoC guidelines? Cheers :)

Comment: +1 Best read on the topic. @bean Mark Seemann also has a very interesting [blog](http://ploeh.blog.dk/)

Comment: @bean: There are lot's of myths and misconceptions around DI and this book clearly shows you the patterns and the anti-patterns. After a few chapters you will have enough information to get started on your project and once you finish the book, you will be a DI jedi, just as Sebastian and I are ;-)

Comment: Well that sounds like a no brainer then. Will just have to trust you on the Jedi part :)

Comment: @SebastianWeber: Will can back me up on this :-D